# How to integrate Core Data to my existing application?

Tags: iphone, database, ios, ipad, core-data

I have selected window based universal application and started coding for my app.

Now i got a requirement to use database and i found that CoreData is more preferable.

Is there any way to add Coredata to my current project, if yes how?

-Mrunal

Comment: Yes, no problem with that. I did it two times with my projects. Right now I haven't time to describe all the way, but the simplest solution for you is to create empty window based project and a project with CoreData - and to compare :) If you aren't succeed and nobody answers you question, I'll right a brief instruction tonight. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GettingStartedWithCoreData/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005316) or the documentation for more details that are open for developers only. This guide is very helpful and there are the [CoreDataBooks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html) and [iPhoneCoreDataRecipes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html) sample codes to get you started.

For a quick solution, create a new navigation controller project and tick the Core Data checkbox. Then copy the Core Data methods that you are missing. You can also use the Core Data code snippets that are available in the Xcode library.

Comment: Thanks.. The link which you have posted is really helpful.