# Code that Xcode puts in if I check "Use Core Data"

Tags: core-data, master-detail

I want to create a project with Core Data, but I don't want to select the Use Core Data checkbox here as in the figure, because I am creating a master-detail application and I want to directly access the detail view controller, and if I use core data, Xcode creates an run-time error.

**Figure**

[image]

So my question is, what is the code that Xcode "puts in" if I check that "Use Core Data" checkbox?

Comment: Your question is unclear: *"if I use core data, Xcode creates an run-time error"* What error? What is your code? - *"what is the code that Xcode puts in"* Just activate the checkbox and look at the code.

Comment: Okay.  I want to access the Detail View Controller directly and not from clicking any cell in the Master View Controller.  But, if I use Core Data, I cannot do that because it will create a run-time error.

Comment: Without seeing your *code* and the *complete error message* it is impossible to help. But as it seems, your problem is solved.

Comment: Yeah.  I think it is, for I am looking at the website that @Matt posted, and it still seems okay.

Comment: just create a new project with that checkbox checked and look at the code. It's not much code, and nothing fancy is done in the project. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026000/adding-core-data-to-an-existing-iphone-app http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528341/how-to-add-core-data-to-an-existing-utility-application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255815/how-to-integrate-core-data-to-my-existing-application